# Draw an ASCII Grid

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, printable-ascii

(Based on [this closed challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229794/drawing-a-grid-using-and-in-python-using-the-least-bytes-possible#229794), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58243/16-bit-binary-grid))

Given an integer n > 1, draw a grid composed of the characters: "-" "+" and "|". However, since I want the grid to look nice, the horizontal component should be 2 wide.

Trailing spaces for each line are not required.

##### Examples:

n = 2

```
  | 
--+--
  |
```

n = 3

```
  |  | 
--+--+--
  |  | 
--+--+--
  |  |
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/23526#23526)

Comment: [_Somewhat_ related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/116110/58974)

Comment: @DLosc that's generally allowed, so yes

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda n:f'\n{"--+"*~-n}--\n'.join(['  |'*~-n]*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk09Jq9aSVdXW0mrTjevVlc3Jk9dLys/M08jWl1BoUYdJBqrlaf5Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw0hHwUzTikuhoCgzr0QjTSNTUxPG0fwPAA)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>67</s>  66 bytes

Recursive.

```javascript
f=(n,k=n*2*(n*=3)-n)=>k--?` -|+
`[k%n?~-k%n%3&2|k/n&1:4]+f(n,k):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfbNk/LSEsjT8vWWFM3T9PWLltX1z5BQbdGmyshOls1z75OF0iqGqsZ1WTr56kZWpnEaqeB9Glaqav/T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNMw0tTkQhUxxhAx0dT8DwA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>61</s>  58 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @EliteDaMyth*

The straightforward way.

```javascript
n=>`${s='  |'[R='repeat'](--n)}
${'--+'[R](n)}--
`[R](n)+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5BpbrYVl1BoUY9OshWvSi1IDWxRD1WQ1c3T7OWS6VaXVdXGygTqwHk6upyJUCY2sX/k/PzivNzUvVy8tM10jSMNDW5kEVQeWkaxgTkTTQ1/wMA)

Comment: [61 -> 58, but doesnt print a newline at the end](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5BpbrYVl1BoUY9OshWvSi1IDWxRD1WQ1c3T7OWS6VaXVdXGygTqwHk6upyJUCY2sX/k/PzivNzUvVy8tM10jSMNDW5kEVQeWkaxgTkTTQ1/wMA)

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, <s>70 62 60</s> 58 bytes

```python
lambda n:f"-{'-+-'*~-n}-\n".join([f" {' | '*~-n} \n"]*n)
```

Thanks to @Underslash, @Jonathan Allan for removing 4 bytes.

Comment: You can shave off two bytes by removing f= from the beginning as anonymous functions are allowed.

Comment: Save two with f-strings - [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfXpSZYhvzPycxNyklUSHPSiNNSbdaXVdbV12rTjevVjcmT0lTLys/M08jOk1JoVpdoUYBIqMAlInVytP8X1CUmVeiATJHw1RT8z8A).

Comment: This is some of the hardest to follow Python I've ever seen!

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
“+--“|  ”ẋḊ¥⁺€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxxtXV0gWaOg8Khh7sNd3Q93dB1a@qhx16OmNf8Pt0f@/28KAA)

-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Returns a matrix of characters.

```
“+--“|  ”ẋḊ¥⁺€  Main Link
“+--“|  ”       ["+--", "|  "]
           ¥    Apply last two to a list and X
         ẋ      Repeat the list X times
          Ḋ     Remove the first element
             €  To each row,
            ⁺   Do the above
```

Comment: Well that was fast

Comment: @SlamJammington [i am speed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/222905/possible-periods-of-input/222906#comment517078_222906)

Comment: Save two using `¥`, `⁺`, and some reordering of operations [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxxtXV0gWaOg8Khh7sNd3Q93dB1a@qhx16OmNf8Pt0f@/28KAA).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, I had a feeling there had to be some way of getting around the chaining without requiring a `µ`. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＵＯ⊖×³Ｎ⊖⊗θ  |¶--+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L13DJTW5KDU3Na8kNUUjJDM3tVjDWEfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU1NTRwFZlUt@aVIOkC4ESSgpKNTE5OnqaitpWv//b/xftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＯ
```

Draw a rectangle...

```
⊖×³Ｎ
```

... width `3n-1`...

```
⊖⊗θ
```

... height `2n-1`...

```
  |¶--+
```

... filled with   `|` and `--+` on alternate lines.

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `rj`, 15 bytes

```
`+--|  `½*ẋfḢvḢ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rj&code=%60%2B--%7C%20%20%60%C2%BD*%E1%BA%8Bf%E1%B8%A2v%E1%B8%A2&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

Port of [hyper-neutrino's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229980/80050)

Comment: Nice use of the split to save some bytes

Comment: [Ninja'd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229979/draw-an-ascii-grid/229983?noredirect=1#comment527874_229983)

Comment: wow you beat charcoal

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 42 bytes

```hs
n%a=tail$[1..n]>>a
f n=n%[n%"+--",n%"|  "]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcgxCgIxEAXQ3lN8BgO7aAIKlpkTaGUZU0zh4mB2CGvsvHtUBKsH7yaP@7WU3s1JbKJlnXYhWGaW1QSL5pI52nhP248vgHKfRQ0Rs9QThovCM@qi1qBg/nV9tnNbjoZhgo7f/g/RiLQP4ZD7Gw)

Defines `f :: Integer -> [String]`.

`[1..n]>>a` means: for each element of `[1..n]`, cycle through all elements of `a`. Then, `tail` removes the first one. So `3%"+--"` evaluates to `"--+--+--"`.

`%` does double duty, first acting on `String`s to make the two grid rows, and then on `[String]` to transform them into whole grid.

(The tempting 39-byte `f n|g<-tail.([1..n]>>)=g[g"+--",g"|  "]` is thus foiled by the  [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).)

Answer (score 7):

## Excel, 62 bytes

```
=LEFT(REPT(IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(2*A1-1),2),"  |","--+"),A1),3*A1-1)
```

With gridlines turned off, it looks the same as the single string with line feeds.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
->n{['  |'*~-n]*n*"
#{['--']*n*?+}
"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlpdQaFGXatONy9WK09LiUsZKKKrqw7i2GvXcinV/k/LL1LIVMjMUzDS0zPlUigoLSlWSIvOjIUwuVLzUv4DAA)

#### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

A very similar approach, also 37 bytes:

```ruby
->n{['  |'*~-n]*n*"
#{'--+'*~-n}--
"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlpdQaFGXatONy9WK09LiUu5Wl1XVxssUKury6VU@z8tv0ghUyEzT8FIT8@US6GgtKRYIS06MxbC5ErNS/kPAA)

Comment: [35 if author allows taking function input as n-1](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlpdQaFGXSsvVku3Lk9LiUu5Wl1XVxsoUKury6VU@z8tv0ghUyEzT8FIT8@US6GgtKRYIS06U9cwFsLhSs1L@Q8A)

Answer (score 7):

## APL, 44 bytes

```
{1 1↓⊃⍪/,/⍵ ⍵⍴⊂2 3⍴'+--|  '}
```

`2 3⍴'+--|  '` gives:

```
+--
|
```

`⍵ ⍵⍴⊂2 3⍴'+--|  '` gives n×n tiles, and `⍪/,/` joins them together.
For example n = 3:

```
 +--+--+--
 |  |  |  
 +--+--+--
 |  |  |  
 +--+--+--
 |  |  |
```

And finally `1 1↓⊃` discloses and drops the first column and row.

```
  |  |  
--+--+--
  |  |  
--+--+--
  |  |
```

Works in both Dyalog APL and GNU APL.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqQwXDR22TH3U1P@pdpa@j/6h3qwIQP@rd8qiryUjBGMhQ19bVrVFQUK8F6lAw4kpTMAUA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: You might want to add a [TIO](https://tio.run/#apl-dyalog) link so others can test your code online.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 19 bytes

```
:`+--``|  `"*$ẋfḢvḢ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%3A%60%2B--%60%60%7C%20%20%60%22*%24%E1%BA%8Bf%E1%B8%A2v%E1%B8%A2&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Ports my Jelly answer. I'll stop for a bit to give other people time to answer.

```
:`+--``|  `"*$ẋfḢvḢ  Full Program
:                    Duplicate X
 `+--`               Push "+--"
      `|  `          Push "|  "
           "         Pair into ["+--", "|  "]
            *        Repeat each X times
             $ẋ      Repeat that X times
               f     Flatten
                Ḣ    Remove first row
                 vḢ  Remove first column from each

j                    flag: output top of stack separated by newlines
```

Comment: [s/Ports/Beats](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=%60%2B--%7C%20%20%60%C2%BD*%E1%BA%8Bf%E1%B8%A2v%E1%B8%A2&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller Looks like I was beaten to golfing it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
@>*@>:["+--""|  "]XaRLa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fwU7Lwc4qWklbV1dJqUZBQSk2IjHIJ/H///@6Of@NAQ)

#### Explanation

Same idea as [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230001/16766), implemented a bit more directly:

```
      ["+--""|  "]       List of two strings
                  Xa     Repeat each string n times
                    RLa  Repeat the whole list n times
   @>:                   All but the first item of the list (: forces @> to be
                           lower precedence than X and RL)
@>*                      All but the first item of each string in the list
                         Autoprint (implicit), one string per line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

```
'| +-'{~<:@+:$#:@6(,:+&2)@$~*&3-1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1WsUtHXVq@tsrBy0rVSUrRzMNHSstNWMNB1U6rTUjHUNrf5rcqUmZ@QrpCkYQRjq6jABY3QBk/8A)

Consider 3 as input:

- `#:@6...$~*&3-1:` Six in binary `#:@6` expands to `1 1 0` and "input times 3 minus 1" is 8 `*&3-1:`, so we extend `1 1 0` that far:

  ```
  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
  ```
- `(,:+&2)@` Stack that with 2 added to itself:

  ```
  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
  3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3
  ```
- `<:@+:$` Now extend that to length "2 times input minus 1":

  ```
  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
  3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3
  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
  3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3
  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
  ```
- `'| +-'{~` And use that to index into the grid characters:

  ```
    |  |  
  --+--+--
    |  |  
  --+--+--
    |  |
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 71 bytes

```c
l;f(n){for(l=n*3,n=n*2*l-l;--n;)putchar(n%l?"|  +--"[n/l%2*3+n%3]:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzNCgIhFIX38xQXQfAnqRRaZEMPUi1EsIQ7t5im1eSzm0JncT74DpxoIga614o@CZJres4CR1JuQ62tQoPeGPLy9VniI8yCOJ7ZF0Abwy60RW6V08Td7bjfSV9qpgWmkEnIdYD@1kWGESz4xhMcGrXO0HdIIkvf2N7fgl1J/cO6LUOpPw)

```
l=n*3        line length (\n included)
n=n*2*l-l    total characters count
for(..;--n)  while we iterate backwards :
n%l?..:10    > put a return at end of line or..
"|  +--"[n/l%2*3+n%3] > take the proper char to put
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2 or 3](https://docs.python.org/), <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 42 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546)*

```python
lambda n:([("+--"*n)[1:],"  |"*~-n]*n)[1:]
```

Returns a list of lines. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSiNaQ0lbV1dJK08z2tAqVkdJQaFGSatONy8WKvI/Ma9YwVYhTcNYk4uroCgzr0QDKKIJZSopaXKl5RcpFOWXK2TmKQBlrLgUIFJAIc3/AA)

#### Explanation

It's easy to generate this grid:

```python
+--+--+--
|  |  |  
+--+--+--
|  |  |  
+--+--+--
|  |  |
```

Then we can trim off the first line as well as the first character of each line.

Since the latest golf, the code works a *little* differently:

```python
([("+--"*n)[1:],"  |"*~-n]*n)[1:]
   "+--"*n                         # Repeat the horizontal line pattern n times
  (       )[1:]                    # and remove the first character
                "  |"*~-n          # Repeat the other pattern n-1 times
                                   # (trailing spaces aren't required, so
                                   # we don't have to remove anything)
 [             ,         ]         # Put those two strings in a list
                          *n       # Repeat the list n times
(                           )[1:]  # and remove the first element
```

Comment: Oh nice, haha. In that case, `lambda n:([("+--"*n)[1:],"  |"*~-n]*n)[1:]` should work, as trailing spaces are not required.

Comment: @dingledooper Ah, true. I'm a little disappointed to break the symmetry of it, but bytes is bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## 6502 machine code, Apple 2, 61 bytes

I got a bit carried away...

$130 - $F3 = $3D (61 decimal) bytes

Listing:

```
0000F3r 1               n := $f0
0000F3r 1               c := $f1
0000F3r 1               ; X register contains n
0000F3r 1  86 F0        grid:   stx n
0000F5r 1  CA                   dex
0000F6r 1  86 F1                stx c
0000F8r 1  A6 F1        @loop: ldx c
0000FAr 1  A9 rr        @cloop: lda #<coldiv
0000FCr 1  A0 rr                ldy #>coldiv
0000FEr 1  20 rr rr             jsr msgoutay
000101r 1  CA                   dex
000102r 1  D0 F6                bne @cloop
000104r 1  20 8E FD             jsr CROUT
000107r 1  C6 F0                dec n
000109r 1  F0 19                beq @done
00010Br 1  A6 F1                ldx c
00010Dr 1  A9 rr        @rloop: lda #<rowdiv
00010Fr 1  A0 rr                ldy #>rowdiv
000111r 1  20 rr rr             jsr msgoutay
000114r 1  CA                   dex
000115r 1  D0 F6                bne @rloop
000117r 1  A9 rr                lda #<rowend
000119r 1  A0 rr                ldy #>rowend
00011Br 1  20 rr rr             jsr msgoutay
00011Er 1  20 8E FD             jsr CROUT
000121r 1  4C rr rr             jmp @loop
000124r 1  60           @done:  rts
000125r 1               
000125r 1               
000125r 1  A0 A0 FC 00  coldiv:    ASZ "  |"
000129r 1  AD AD AB 00  rowdiv:   ASZ "--+"
00012Dr 1  AD AD 00     rowend:  ASZ "--"
000130r 1
```

Example run called with

```
    ldx #4
    jsr grid
```

[image: Example Test Run]

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 71 bytes

```
n->[print(concat([["  ","--";"|","+"][j+1,t+1]|j<-r]))|t<-r=[2..2*n]%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAr8hCoOkK2bHsI8seIjDysIl49O/Waaac9cG7jBSH4EGlPtL09cp1Nk0ESoEDRNig/7HAlO3iml245x0rG9Pbb6TgfZiFp8Aj6dWMDw)

Thanks to alephalpha for saving 39 bytes.

Comment: [93 bytes.](https://tio.run/##TYoxCoAwDAC/UjIl1BTUUetHSgcXgwqlFOnUv8fi5HLcweW9nCxZD6@Jt4Di8R4qdc3lTM@IN7Vr5RKXr7ESIRjTYOgEsoLAbHsxA7Wnnz5MzqUYF/mPeuBM@gI "Pari/GP – Try It Online") You can use `;` to execute multiple statements in a function. `;` is not allowed in list comprehensions, but here you can use `+` because the return value of `g` is just `0`. `print1` prints something without a trailing newline.

Comment: Or [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAr8hCoOkK2bHsI8seIjDysIl49O/Waaac9cG7jBSH4EGlPtL09cp1Nk0ESoEDRNig/7HAlO3iml245x0rG9Pbb6TgfZiFp8Aj6dWMDw "Pari/GP – Try It Online").

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
->n{(2..n*2).map{|x|[" -"[x%=2]*2]*n*"|+"[x]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNITy9Py0hTLzexoLqmoiZaSUFXKbpC1dYoVguI8rSUarSB/Nja2v8FpSXFCmnRRrFcIBYXlGsW@x8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>46</s></sup>29 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⍉1↓⍉⊃,/⍵⍴⊂(⍵+⍵-1)3⍴'|  +--'}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37U22n4qG0ykHrU1ayj/6h366PeLY@6mjSALG0g1jXUNAaKqNcoKGjr6qrXAgA&f=S1Mw4kpTMAZiEyA2BQA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

- saved 17 thanks to @Razetime tips!

(⍵+⍵-1)3⍴'|  +--'  we build the entire column e.g.

```
| 
+--
|  
+--
|
```

Then :

```
⍵⍴⊂    ⍝  n copies of that column 
,/     ⍝  concatenate 
⊃      ⍝  disclose
⍉1↓⍉   ⍝ transpose, drop line, re transpose
```

Comment: `1↓[2]` → `⍉1↓⍉`

Comment: @Razetime thanks but it is 1 character shorter but 3 bytes longer..

Comment: All the APL symbols +  ASCII have a [single byte encoding](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS/blob/master/SBCS.dyalog) :)

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 841 bytes

```
->>>>>+++++[>+++++>+++++<<-],[+>-[<-->-]>[>>>>+>+<<<<<-]>>>,]+++[<+++>-]+[-<<<<<[->+>+>+<<<]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<<+]->>>>>->->->>>[<+++++++++[>+>+>+<<<-]>>>>>>]->--[<<+>>-]>[<<+++++>>-]<<[[->>>>>+<<<<<]<]<+[--[>>>>>>>..>.<<<<<<<<-]+<<<<<[[<<<+>>>-]<<<[->>>+>+>+<<<<<]>>>>+>-<[>[[-]<[-]<->>>>>[+++++++++>>>>>]<<<<<+>>>>]<[--<<<<<]]>[++>>>--<<[>>>>>]>]<<]<<+]++++++++++.[-]-<+[--[->>++[-<<<+[->>[-]<<[<+>-]<[>+>>+<<<-]<<<<+]-[>>>>>]<<<+[--[>[>+>-<<-]>[<+>-]>+[->->>>..>.<<<<<]>+[->>>+++++++++++++..--.-----------<<<]<<<<-]+<<<<<[[<<<+>>>-]<<<[->>>+>+>+<<<<<]>>>>+>-<[>[[-]<[-]<->>>>>[+++++++++>>>>>]<<<<<+>>>>]<[--<<<<<]]>[++>>>--<<[>>>>>]>]<<]<<+]>[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>[->>>>+++++++++++++..-------------<<<<]<++++++++++.[-]<]<<]+<<<<<[[<<+>>-]<<[->>+>>+>+<<<<<]>>>>+>-<[>[[-]<[-]<<->>>>>[+++++++++>>>>>]<<<<<+>>>>>]<[--<<<<<]]>[++>>--<[>>>>>]>]<<<]<<+]
```

edit1, thank you for the suggestion by [Radvylf Programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857/radvylf-programs)

this work by using 5 cells per digit, 1 for original number, 1 for row number, 1 for column number, and 2 for verifying that help to make the number system work.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVJBTsQwDLznFb17nRNHyx@xfAAkpBUSByTeX2bsULpoBVfSNmljjz0z6dP74/Xt5eP5dd/VOYQjeunZTPMS4hqm6poelecIGGP4uCRBRoimbKEVCmVW5TEpsApWTb5kt9O6GKxe2@q@YFUcIwey0J94ErDO7loRi3k1TVwSSG6kz@nT1gC3JnZDpeByCMpWpzbCUTqNT3eIg6I0rQJIv6Jn43MMZrI8dppHQgJCg8K/hcpEbTQaRVhpfnsn/IgSZ7TUaMlyxNq9OBgsuEextvKHIGcVPVvQW@uMt2OeUxU3xrbm8vHfGFbK5KysT/yOjJ8q@DPc2g27kp6dlH39RzwA/13W37ruCsPGWdbSte8Pnw)

also, I edited the first one(adding "+" version) to get a better result. here

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck)(adding "+" version) ,<s>273</s> 198 bytes

```
-[>+>+>+<<<-]>>> >>> >>> >+++++[<+++<+++++<<++++++<++>>>>>-]<<[<+++++>-]>[<+++>-]<<-<++<<<[->>>..>.<<<<]>>.<<<<[->[->+>+<<]>[<+>-]>[>>>>..--.++<<<<-]>>>>..<<<.<<<[->+>+<<]>[<+>-]>[>>..>.<<<-]>.<<<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5BCoAwDPuK99G@IPQjYwcVBBE8CL5/Zql4sVvXNEu6Lde8n9u9Hr1kdKtRxgJgLSKmL3VfwQOCyDK6GGENqMkRh6BIwxCjGkXu4cTgaFWS3HpPFjlDQjOXL/9BgtDT8tO/Y9nk9N4f)

Comment: You'll need to use `,` for input according to site rules, using `+`s in the header isn't an allowed input format as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
$_¶$_¶
1
+--
T`-+` |`¶.+¶
1A`
%`^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkEsl/tA2EAYytXV1uUISdLUTFGoSDm3T0wYJOiZwqSbE6XH9/28MAA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1
$_¶$_¶
```

Create `2n` rows of `n` `1`s.

```
1
+--
```

Replace each `1` with `+--`.

```
T`-+` |`¶.+¶
```

Change those to   `|` on alternate lines.

```
1A`
```

Delete the first line of `--+`s.

```
%`^.
```

Delete the leading `+`s or `|`s on each line.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 93 bytes

```javascript
n=>('  |'[r='repeat'](--n)+'  0')[r](n+1).slice(0,-1).split(0).join('\n'+'--+'[r](n)+'--\n');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxDgIhEEDRq2w3M8Eh2NgYvMi6BUHWsCEDAWLl3ZG1@3n5h/u45mssnSW/wtjtEPtAWJYvrNVCDSW4DhsyC6nJBmitG4q6km4p@oDmwmeXFDsa0keOgvAUUMCs4D/T2ZPoPnyWllPQKb9xxxtN@gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╬^û╗i§║╜P◙ƒ═½\
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ce5e96bb6915babd500a9fcdab5c&i=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&m=2)

Similar to the Jelly answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell], 53 bytes

```powershell
&{$c=$n-1;@("  |"*$c)*$n -join "`n$(""--+""*$c)--`n"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZ2vyX61aJdlWJU/X0NpBQ0lBoUZJSyVZU0slT0E3Kz8zT0EpIU9FQ0lJV1dbCSyjq5uQp1T7/z8A)

Comment: Nice answer. Could you provide some way of running this online, maybe via tio.run so others can test it out?